# Project Euler, #1

Tags: java, math, logic

It seems that my code is not working for project Euler, problem 1.
The problem states:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

The output of my program is

> 266333

my code is:

```
private static final int max = 1000;
    private static int sum;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        addMultiples(3);
        addMultiples(5);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static void addMultiples(int mult)
    {
        int x = mult;
        while(x < max)
        {
            sum += x;
            x += mult;
        }
    }
```

It seems that the basic fundamentals of mathematics are simply eluding me, and this really discourages me in becoming a programmer if I'm incapable of finding what seems to be a solution to such a simple problem.

Comment: Hint: 15 is a multiple of 3 __and__ 5.

Comment: you are adding numbers those are multiple of both 3 and 5 twice to the sum.

Comment: OP: don't be upset if you can't get your program to work in your first attempt. _It happens to all of us._

Comment: ?  Well your code is confusing.  You print out the sum in your main function but really sum is being calculated in addMultiples.  Try making 2 extra functions to main.  Main will call the 2 functions.  A logical approach would be to have one function call and return an array of the multiples of the given number with a max (you need to pass in the number AND the max to it).  Then have a separate function (takes in the array) and sum it up.

Comment: Extra Credit Hint: This can be solved without iteration or storing a list of values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, and most importantly, **don't get discouraged**. Its just a problem, and it is a very poor indicator of potential as a programmer. Just keep practicing, and anywho, your error is more math than programming.

If we list numbers that are multiples of 3 less than 16, we get: 3, 6, 9, 12, 15.
If we list numbers that are multiples of 5 less than 16, we get: 5, 10, 15.

See the problem?

You're counting 15 twice. You can probably figure out the implementation, so I won't bother giving you code. That won't make you any better.

Also, this problem can be solved much more efficiently with math and sums, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you did there is adding multiples of 3 **and** 5 like 15 twice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) if(i%3==0 || i%5==0) sum += i;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small error here.

15 is a multiple of 5, and a multiple of 3. So you don't want to count that twice! :)

One thing you could do (this is my functional side speaking) is create a list from 0 to max. You then create a method that takes out all multiples of 3 and adds them to your result list, and removes them from your input list. This now trimmed down list, is passed on to a method that filters out all multiples of 5, and adds them to that same output list.

You take the sum of your list.

Edit: Johannes Trümpelmann's solution is short, readable and more performing, so you might want to go with that one.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was that you didn't take into account that multiplication of your dividers was counted twice. So I suggest you to change `addMultiples` to get an array of dividers and . Check the dividers within a loop if they divide certain numbers.:

```
private static int sum;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    addMultiples(new int[]{3,5});
    System.out.println(sum);
}

private static void addMultiples(int[] mult)
{
    int x = 1;
    while(x < max)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mult.length; i++){
            if(x % mult[i] == 0){
                sum += x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```